# How to configure querydsl in spring boot 1.4.1?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, querydsl

Im trying to enable querydsl using spring-data-jpa for a project, however Im getting some compilation errors like:

```
The type com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Also, when I run mvn clean install I get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryEntities
```

I review the jar in my classpath and I can see querydsl-core 4.1.4, querydsl-apt 4.1.4 and querydsl-jpa 4.1.4.  But the project still not compiling for me, is there any issue with springboot 1.4.1 and querydsl?

I have this in my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and the plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

--- UPDATE ---

I downgrade from querydsl 4.1.4 to 4.1.3 and at least is compiling the project.  Now, I can start some testing I will post my findings.

I think the question still open, because by default spring boot 1.4.1 comes with querydsl 4.1.4 version.

Comment: Did you add the plugin above on build > plugin  OR build > pluginmanagement > plugin. You need to put the plugin on build > plugin

Answer (score 1):

Put dependencies in the plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Same error, which is weird to me because I see that core has the classes that eclipse is looking for, but for some reason is not picking the class

Comment: Run eclipse:eclipse to update eclipse project classpath

Comment: Still not working.   When I run eclipse:eclipse I got "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryEntities".

Comment: You tried `eclipse:eclipse` with querydsl dependencies inside or outside apt-maven-plugin?